# Get data from mongoose (mongoDB) and show it to jade view

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I know there were people with simillar problem, however, i have not made to fix mine according to previous answers...

I want to get data from *mongoDB* and show it in the Jade view (in a list). However, i get an empty view. Only *h1* tag is visible.

My goal is to extract *message.content*  from each *message* in the database.

Please help!

here is the code:

**//my nodejs route to get all messages**

```
router.get('/getMessages', function(req, res){
  Message.find(function (err, messages){
    res.render('getMessages', {messages: messages});
  });
});


**//this is my jade view where i am trying to extract content of my message**

extends layout

block content
  .container
    h1 Register Page
each message in messages
 p
  #{message.content}
```

Comment: try to put each at the same level of h1

Answer (score 0):

try to put each at the same level

```
extends layout

block content
  .container
    h1 Register Page
    each message in messages
     p
      #{message.content}
```

Comment: Nothing changes. If i put "each" statement at the same level with "h1" it gives me an error...

Comment: > 7| #{message.content} Cannot read property 'content' of undefined.  This is the message. Unless i dont understand how do you mean to "put each at the same level of h1".

Comment: You said that Only h1 tag is visible, when you put each at the same level as h1 so the display problem is set, now the error is that message.content does not exist, you must first verify that what you get from the base

Comment: Are you still stuck on this? "Cannot read property 'content' of undefined" sounds like your messages object isn't being passed to your Jade view properly, or perhaps is being passed as an empty object. It's a little while since I've done Mongoose queries, but perhaps you need to change your query slightly to return all the messages. Something like `Messages.find({}, function...` (although I might be wrong about that.). Try console.log(messages) after your Mongoose query to see what you're getting back.